# Javascript: Need to replace an object in an HTML code which is stored as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I am working on a website that shows different APIs we provide. It showcases the example code and preview for each API and a button to open code in plunker. Since we have 100s of examples, we are not creating plunker for every example, but opening a new tab "https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview" and appending the corresponding html code into it.

**Problem:**

I have a total HTML document as a string in a javascript variable.

```
var html = "`<DOCTYPE html><html>....<body><script>abc.loader.load({apiToken:'', name:'',...});</script></body>`"
```

I have to change the object inside `abc.loader.load()`. Is there any way I can pick up the object inside `abc.loader.load()` and make changes in javascript and replace with existing object.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a template library.

Comment: Yeah, I would recommend looking at EJS, Handlebars, or Jade.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template literal and inject `${JSON.stringify(obj)}` into that, like this:

```js
<!--
var obj = {apiToken:'', name:''};
var html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html>....<body>
            <script>abc.loader.load(${JSON.stringify(obj)});</script></body></html>`;
   
console.log(html);
-->
```

The script content is wrapped in `<!--   -->` to avoid misinterpretation of `<` inside your string.

#### Reading out the object and writing it again after mutation:

Although I would try to stick to the above template string, and would repeat the injection of different objects into it, here is what you could do when you have a given HTML string, and need to extract the object. This only works if the object literal is JSON compliant, i.e. it double quotes strings, and also property names:

```js
<!--
var html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html>....<body>
            <script>abc.loader.load({"apiToken":"", "name":""});</script></body></html>`;
html = html.replace(/(loader\.load\()(.*?)(?=\);<\/script>)/, function (_, prefix, json) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(json); // get the object
    obj.test = 3; // modify the object as you wish
    return prefix + JSON.stringify(obj); // put the object
});
console.log(html);
-->
```